# Height for UITableViewCell containing UITableView (iOS8 and AutoLayout)

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, ios8

I have a UITableView with custom cells that also contain UITableViews. I'm having problems getting the height for these cells.

I'm getting the height in heightForRowAtIndexPath and to do this I populate the child tableView (within the cell) and call layoutIfNeeded. This gives me the correct contentSize for this tableView. The problem is that the overall size for the cell is wrong and doesn't change. So calling cell.bounds.height returns an incorrect value.

```
        let cell:GroupCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("GroupCell") as GroupCell
        cell.configure(field as SingleField, delegate: self) // populates data
        cell.tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
        // cell.tableView.contentSize is correct
        return cell.bounds.height // is wrong - bounds haven't changed
```

[image: Cell Autolayout]

Can anyone point me in the right direction ? BTW - I'm targeting iOS8 only.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create subclass of UITableViewCell, add TableView delegates to it, use it like usual.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, my custom cell already does this. The problem is the parent UITableView can't get the correct size for this cell.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in UITableView. You've sad table have correct content size, but it have incorrect size. After calculating the correct content size you should change tableView height manually. I think it will help you. Tip: you can observe contentSize property and every time it will be changed you can resize table view. To do this - add height constrain to your table with low priority (750 for example) and than just change it when needed. In this case your table will have both content size and self.frame.heigh equal.

Comment: Thanks Seliver, interesting angle. I could calculate the size of the label, margins, etc. and add them to the tableview content size. I was hoping that with autolayout constraints this would have happened automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this as follows:

1. I put a height constraint (Greater than or equal to) on the UITableView (within the Cell). I set the priority of this to High
2. I set the priority of the bottom margin to Low
3. When configuring my custom cell I call setNeedsUpdateConstraints(), which invalidates the height constraint by removing it, and then recalculates it from the content size of the table view before adding it back.
4. Finally, in heightForRowAtIndexPath cell.contentView.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height now returns the correct height

   ```
   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

      let field = fields[indexPath.row]

      let cell:GroupCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("GroupCell") as GroupCell
      cell.configure(field as SingleField, delegate: self)
      return cell.contentView.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height
   }

   func configure(field:SingleField,delegate:GroupDelegate){

      self.field = field
      self.delegate = delegate
      nameLabel.text = field.name
      tableView.reloadData()
      setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
   }


   override func updateConstraints() {
      tableView.removeConstraint(tableViewHeightConstraint)
      tableViewHeightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: tableView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: tableView.contentSize.height)
      tableView.addConstraint(tableViewHeightConstraint)
      super.updateConstraints()
   }
   ```